# How to apply for loop in any variable in python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I want to apply for loop in msg variable in python.
there is two variables called names & car_no(from sql queries  am getting this).

Type of variable:

```
car_no = <class 'int'>
names = <class 'str'>
input sample: names & car_no
jhon
198
pig
144
carlet
36
Mona
144
rahul
510
```

like that 100 names and car_no is there, want to iterate all this names and car_no in msg.(that msg is for send mail to recipents(HTML format))

Required output is :

```
<html>
                                 <head></head>
                                 <body>
                                   <p>Dear jhon</p>
                                   <p>your bday list:</br>
                                     jhon - 199</br>
                                      pig - 144</br>
                                     carlet -36</br>
                                      mona - 144</br>
                                      rahul - 510</br

                                   <p>
                                   Thanks</br>

                                   </p>
                                   </body>
                          </html>
```

I want to apply for loop on this two variable for iterate it in other variable called msg(its html quote)

```
msg = f'''<html>
                                 <head></head>
                                 <body>
                                   <p>Dear jhon</p>
                                   <p>your bday list:</br>
                                    \t{str(names)} -\t{str(car_no)}</br>
                                   <p>
                                   Thanks</br>

                                   </p>
                                   </body>
                          </html>'''
```

I tried:

```
for query in _queries:
    # print(query)
    cur.execute(query)
    fetch= cur.fetchone().items()
    names = list(fetch)[0][0]
    car_no= list(fetch)[0][1]
    print("names:", type(names))
    print("car_no:", type(car_no))
    # for k, v in fetch.items():
    #     print(k,v)
    for n in names:
        for v in range(car_no):
            message = f'''<html>
                                 <head></head>
                                 <body>
                                   <p>Dear jhon</p>
                                   <p>your bday list:</br>
                                    \t{str(names)} -\t{str(car_no)}</br>
                                   <p>
                                   Thanks</br>

                                   </p>
                                   </body>
                          </html>'''
```

But its not iterating well, its having 100 records and i want all names and car_no in one msg.
can you guys please guide me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data is in two separate lists (which is not quite clear to me from your question) like this:

```
names = [ 'jhon', 'pig', 'carlet', 'Mona', 'rahul' ]
car_no = [ 198, 144, 36, 144, 510 ]
```

Then you can iterate over the two lists using the `zip` function. And of course, the loop must create only the actual list of data for the `message`, whereas the leading and trailing parts must be created outside of the loop.

```
message = f'''<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Dear jhon</p>
    <p>your bday list:</br>\n'''

for n, c in zip(names, car_no):
    message += f'    {n} - {c}</br>\n'

message += f'''    <p>Thanks</br>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>'''
```